# Errors for form in rendered template

Tags: forms, symfony

I have this :

- template edit.html.twig

  ```
  {% extends "....:...:layout.html.twig" %}

      {% block body %}        
          {{ render(controller('EVeilleurFlowerBundle:Catalogue:add' )) }}
          {{ render(controller('EVeilleurFlowerBundle:Catalogue:delete' )) }}
      {% endblock %}
  ```
- And the template "add" is basically a single form.

When the user enters "wrong" data in the add form, it automatically redirects to add.html.twig, displaying a single form ( wtih the error ) without layout, css etc...

Can i change the redirection, or am I building my templates the wrong way ? (pretty much newbie here :) )

Thanks

Comment: How does you form tag look like in Catalogue/add.html.twig? What action do you use there? I guess the form action point to CatalogueController->addAction()?

Comment: yes it's a simple form with a controller. in my class Catalogue I have addAction and deleteAction. My problem is when the form is not validated it redirects to catalogue/add but i want it to redirect to catalogue/edit, to keep the whole page..

Comment: Just must make sure that the form tag has the valid action, like '<form action="{{ path('your_destination_route') }}"...>'. your_destination_route should NOT point to Catalogue:add

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

Comment: Sry i'm a bit late... so when i do the action path to edit it works well for the layout and all, but now the errors are not displayed... I also read the doc but i can't find my issue